# How do I test loaded data into a reactive form with Jasmine in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, angular6

I have an Angular 6 app that loads data into a **Reactive Form** from a store object using **ngrx**.  I am trying to unit test this but seems like no matter what I change my form object always has blank values for the properties I am assigning.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate>
    <input id="name" formControlName="name" />
    <input id="age" formControlName="age" />
</form>
```

**Component**

```
export interface MyObject {
    name: string;
    age: string;
}

export class MyObjectComponent {
    myObject: MyObject;
    myForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private store: Store<fromStore.State>) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myForm = this.fb.group({
            name: [null, [Validators.required]],
            age: [null, [Validators.required]]
        });
        this.store.select(fromStore.getMyObject).subscribe(x => this.myForm.patchValue(x));
}
```

**spec file**

```
describe('MyObjectComponent', () => {
    let component: MyObjectComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyObjectComponent>;
    let store: Store<fromStore.State>;
    let initialStateL MyObject;
    let el: DebugElement;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        initialState = {
            name: 'My Name',
            age: 55
        };
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                FormsModule,
                ReactiveFormsModule,
                HttpClientModule,
                StoreModule.forRoot({}),
                StoreModule.forFeature('my-object', reducer)
            ],
            declarations: [MyObjectComponent],
            providers: []
        })
        .compileComponents().then(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyObjectComponent);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;
            el = fixture.debugElement;
            spyOn(store, 'dispatch').and.callThrough();
            fixture.detectChanges();
        });
    }));

    it('should patch values into form', async(() => {
        expect(component.myForm.controls.age.value).toBe(55);
    }
}
```

The test always fails saying the value in the form is nothing.  Anyone know what I am doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: You're getting that error because "value" is undefined, initialState is never assigned to the form.

Comment: @Danny908, but how do I get initial state to be assigned to the mock store?  I have seen articles that create their own mock store class, pass it in with a reducer map, or use the `Store.forRoot` directly.

Comment: Hi again I leave you more details below

Answer (score 2):

here is the assignation in details:

First create the mock values for the form, access to your form and assign the value then you need to trigger change detection on the component and finally test the value of the input.

I haven't test this code yet, but I think is really close about what are you trying to do.

```
describe('MyObjectComponent', () => {

// Rest of code...

it('should patch values into form', async(() => {
    // Mock value
    const mock_age_value = 55;

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DualityAccordionTabComponent);
    const compiled = fixture.componentInstance;

    // Value assignation
    compiled.myForm.patchValue({
       age: mock_age_value
    });

    // Trigger change detection
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.myForm.controls.age.value).toBe(55);
}


}
```

Comment: Also you said something about running Store directly.  Try running "compiled.ngOnInit()" directly on your test  and then trigger change detection, that should made the work

Comment: thanks for the response!  What if I want to mock the store and load data into the form from the mock store and test from there?  Do I need to mock the form data instead?  Preferably I would like to test the store correctly dumps data into the form in the unit test.